# How to adjust the legend length in rworldmap?

Tags: r, rworldmap

I would like to adjust the legend bar of rworldmap.

```
    mapCountryData(df, 
                   nameColumnToPlot="users",
                   xlim=NA,
                   ylim=NA,
                   mapRegion="World",
                   numCats=30,
                   catMethod="pretty",
                   addLegend=TRUE,
                   mapTitle="map1",
                   colourPalette=c("heat")) 
    do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapParams, legendLabels="all",
                           legendWidth=0.5,
                           legendIntervals="data",
                           legendMar=2))
```

I was able to generate the map, but failed to adjust the legend bar. The legend layout was across the map, which did not look well.

> Error in do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapParams, legendLabels = "all", legendWidth = 0.5,  : 
>     object 'mapParams' not found

I am not able to provide the dataset. Can anyone help review which part of my scripts generates the error and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `mapParams <-` to the start of your first line.

Also have a look at package `tmap` which is more up-to-date than `rworldmap`.

More generally, Stackoverflow recommends that you create a small 'reproducible' example, that would allow people to recreate your issue and test solutions.

Good luck.

```
mapParams <- mapCountryData(df, 
                   nameColumnToPlot="users",
                   xlim=NA,
                   ylim=NA,
                   mapRegion="World",
                   numCats=30,
                   catMethod="pretty",
                   addLegend=TRUE,
                   mapTitle="map1",
                   colourPalette=c("heat")) 

do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapParams, legendLabels="all",
                       legendWidth=0.5,
                       legendIntervals="data",
                       legendMar=2))
```

Comment: Finally got the map I expected! I also adjusted: addLegend=FALSE in the mapParams statement & legendShrink=0.6 in the do.call statement. Will also try package tmap. Much appreciated!