# How to resolve the legend size and its text issue?

Tags: r, legend

I am running some analysis and trying to create a heatmap, this is my code

```
library(rworldmap)

d <- data.frame(
  country=c("Argentina", "Austria","Bangladesh", "Brazil","Canada", "China", "Croatia", "Egypt",
            "Finland", "Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "India", "Iran", "Ireland", "Italy", "Japan", "Jordan", "Malaysia", "Morocco", "Mexico", "Netherlands","New Zealand","Norway"
            ,"Pakistan", "Poland", "Portugal", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saudi Arabia", "Singapore", 
            "South Korea", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Thailand", "United Kingdom", "USA"),
  value=c(3,2,1,7,1,9,1,4,3,10,5,1,43,3,1,18,3,1,24,1,1,11,2,1,11,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,17,5,1,2,32))
n <- joinCountryData2Map(d, joinCode="NAME", nameJoinColumn="country")
mapCountryData(n,nameColumnToPlot="value",catMethod= 'fixedWidth',mapTitle="Representation of publications on the world map")
```

However, when the heatmap is generated, the legend is too big and not in proportion with the graph. The same error happens with another igraph code. Lately, for any analysis, my lagends are not being the default ones. They have changed. Anyways to fix this?[image]

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314761/how-to-adjust-the-legend-length-in-rworldmap

Comment: Looks like your margins are badly adjusted. Try to reset them.